# downloadTaskWithURL how to get the actual data

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I am trying to downlaod an image.

This is the link of the image

https://www.google.it/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png

what I did is:

```
   let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.google.it/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png")
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.downloadTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {(url, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("error = \(error)")
            }

            if let response = response {
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

        })
        task.resume()
```

really i have a response, and i can see it in the log as the following:

```
response = <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fc1a1427060> { URL: https://www.google.it/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "private, max-age=31536000";
    "Content-Length" = 13504;
    "Content-Type" = "image/png";
    Date = "Mon, 23 Nov 2015 23:57:55 GMT";
    Expires = "Mon, 23 Nov 2015 23:57:55 GMT";
    "Last-Modified" = "Fri, 04 Sep 2015 22:33:08 GMT";
    Server = sffe;
    "alt-svc" = "quic=\"www.google.com:443\"; p=\"1\"; ma=600,quic=\":443\"; p=\"1\"; ma=600";
    "alternate-protocol" = "443:quic,p=1";
    "x-content-type-options" = nosniff;
    "x-xss-protection" = "1; mode=block";
} }
```

my problem is that there is no **data** in the response to get the actual image. I used to call the `dataTaskWithRequest` and the clouser for it have a data like this:

```
session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error)
```

but here i didn't find the data, what is my wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

When using a "download" task, you need to implement a session delegate method to get the data. Download tasks put the data into a temporary file, then call the delegate to tell it where that file is located.

If you implement `URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:` in your download delegate, that method will be called with a file URL pointing to the temporary file.

If the images aren't too big, you can use data-style tasks instead. They download the data to memory, then give you an `NSData` object in the completion handler.

Comment: sound so good, but please how can i add that delege?

Comment: i understand that i have to make a class that adopt to a protocol ,and i have to write the function `did finish download to url` right? if yes what is the protocl and how to tell the session to use it ?

Comment: `NSURLSession` has a property called `delegate`, which can be any object that adopts the `NSURLSessionDelegate` protocol. You need to have an object that adopts the protocol and assign it to that property.

Comment: there is no `didFinishDownloadingToURL` function inside the `NSURLSessionDelegate ` protocol. is it the correct method ?

Comment: The [documentation for `NSURLSessionDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDelegate_protocol/) explains that *"In addition to the methods defined in this protocol, most delegates should also implement some or all of the methods in the NSURLSessionTaskDelegate, NSURLSessionDataDelegate, and NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate protocols to handle task-level events."*

Comment: are you saying that i should also conform to these three new protocols? (thanks for your understanding i am new to swift, and to ios in general )

Comment: sounds like the delegate property in the sesion is a read only, and i can't assign values to it.

Comment: My mistake, you should be using `sessionWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue:` when you create the session object.

Comment: can you give me a simple code please? sounds like you are an expert, and i am still in defining my class `class imageDelegate: NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate  {
     @objc func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {
        print("asdfasf")
    }
}` with a lot of errors

Comment: even this sesionWithConfiguration, i dind't know where to add it inside my         let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession(), i tried to sounds like this method is in another place

Comment: I would suggest this Objective-C example as a starting point: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW14